# A faster way to extract geometry xy of geodataframe

Tags: coordinates, geopandas, shapely, geodataframe, code-review

I need a faster way to extract geometry xy of a large dataset which is in a geodataframe format.
I have developed a lambda function as below to do that but I need a faster way.
The following is a simple data with 3 MultiLineString lines to show the way I have coded.
This code on a geodataframe with 100000 rows takes 5 seconds for x coordinates.

```
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString

coord1 = [((0, 0), (1, 1))]
coord2 = [((-1, 0), (1, 0))]
coord3 = [((1, 0), (0, 1))]

lines1 = MultiLineString(coord1)
lines2 = MultiLineString(coord2)
lines3 = MultiLineString(coord3)

d = {'col1': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
     'geometry': [lines1, lines2, lines3]}
gdf = GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:4326")

aa = list(gdf.geometry)
x_list = list(map(lambda x: list(list(x.geoms)[0].coords.xy[0]) , aa))
y_list = list(map(lambda x: list(list(x.geoms)[0].coords.xy[1]) , aa))
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the code you provided does not extract ALL of the coordinates of the MultiLineString geometries. It only extracts the coordinates of the **first** `geom` within each MultiLineString geometry. In the example you gave, the geometries only have one `geom`, so it works out fine. But depending on what you really want to extract, you might need to change your strategy.

Comment: It will likely add A LOT of overhead, so I'm not sure this is even worth it, but one way to try to speed this up would be to use a multiprocessing approach.